# How to get a reference/pointer to a class (not an object)?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a `std::map` where `key` is `string` and I want the `value` to be, not an object, but a `reference/pointer to a class` which I can instantiate.

`std::map<::std::string, ?class_reference?> handlers_;`

Once the specific entry is chosen, I want to create instance of the class and execute a member function.

Comment: C++ doesn't have reflection, like Java, or C# has, if that's what you're asking about.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I didn't know what this was called.

Comment: Set the value to function, which you can define to create the class you want and return a reference to it.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Comment: @ravenspoint `the value to function`? I don't want to create the object because there are dozens of them.

Comment: @G.M. I think that would work. I can create `string -> enum` map and based on the enum, create specific class.

Comment: "How to get a reference/pointer to a class (not an object)?" - You cannot.

Comment: G. M. took the words right out of my mouth. A factory pattern is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have already mentioned, if you want to create relevant objects via a string (such as class name), you'll need to use factory pattern which can create related objects (same base class). Here's a simple example easy to understand (you just store lambda which returns objects in the map):

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class Base {};

class A : public Base{
    public:
    A() { std::cout << "A ctr" << std::endl; }
};

class B : public Base {
    public:
    B() { std::cout << "B ctr" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, std::function<Base*()> > m;
    m["a"] = []() { return new A(); };
    m["b"] = []() { return new B(); };
    m["a"]();
    m["b"]();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to get a reference/pointer to a class (not an object)?

Short answer, you can't. Unfortunately, C++ doesn't work that way.

However, to solve your specific problem, you have the option of a [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), which would look something like this:

```
template <class T>
class factory {
    public:
        virtual std::unique_ptr<T> createObject() = 0;
};

class base { // some base class common to all the types you are intending to create

};

class foo : public base { // some class you want to create

};

class fooCreator : public fatory<base> {
    public:
        std::unique_ptr<T> createObject() {
            return someUniquePointerToANewObject;
        }
}


int main() {
    std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<factory<base>>> myMap; // because we are creating some bases

    myMap["some key"] = new myFooCreator;

    // now let's create some new `base`
    if(myMap.find("some matching key") != myMap.end()) {
        std::unique_ptr<base> myBaseObject = myMap["some matching key"]->createObject();

        // use created object
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, there are a lot of things that could go wrong here, like if for some reason you push a `nullptr` to `myMap`. But at least you have an idea of what it looks like now.

Comment: How is `myFooCreator` a `factory<base>`?

Comment: Whoops. Typo. fixed now.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks. Anything else I missed?

Comment: There are several online compilers (to test code and provide demo), I suggest to use one and provide links when possible, that allow to fix "typos".

Comment: Ignoring typos, you do 2 lookup whereas you might use only one: Store result of `find`.

Comment: @Jarod42 The code has things like `someUniquePointerToANewObject`. The example isn't intended to directly compile. It is an example.